# Problem to edit a function loaded from a namespace

Tags: r, namespaces, mlr

I would like to temporarily modify **selectFeatures** function from mlr package. But something goes wrong when I try to do this (with **assignInNamespace** function) since **selectFeatures** is never modified as I wish (see code below). What is going on ?

*Note : **reassignInPackage** function is also useless*

```
library(mlr)

assignInNamespace("selectFeatures",function(){},"mlr")
getFromNamespace("selectFeatures","mlr") #selectFeatures in mlr namespace seems modified
selectFeatures #Shows the initial selectFeatures function !
environment(selectFeatures) #Shows that selectFeatures is in mlr namespace, so it should be modified !
```

Comment: I never used this way to make changes to a function. Why don't you just use a local fork of the package and modify the function there and then install the changed package? In addition this sounds to be more a general problem than a `mlr` one.

Comment: @pat-s Yes I could modify the source as well but I think assignInNamespace is quite useful to do a temporary edit of a package function. The thing I want to understand is why I have 2 objects from the same namespace with the same name but which are different ! Of course this is not a mlr specific problem